# When are there analytic results for hierarchical-Bayesian models?

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian

When, if ever, are there analytic solutions to hierarchical models? For example, under what conditions can we find an analytic form for the distribution of $X$ in the network below? $X$ has one parameter, which in turn has one hyperparameter.

[image]

For my actual application, I'm using a lognormal distribution where the parameters are themselves uncertain. That is,

\begin{align}
X &\sim \ln(\mu, \sigma^2)  \\
&\quad\text{  and}  \\
\mu &\sim D_1(x, y)  \\
\sigma &\sim D_2(a, b)
\end{align}

Where $D_1$ and $D_2$ are some unspecified distributions. The distributions of the mu and sigma are suggested in some sources to also be lognormal distributions. However, consider a free hand for the distribution of the hyperparameters if it makes an analytic form possible. Can we find parameters mu' and sigma' which are point values, such that $X \sim \ln(\mu', \sigma'^2)$ (or perhaps for some another distribution which isn't lognormal)?